# Executing multiple commands in sequence in GIMP

Tags: gimp, automation

I've been working with GIMP for some time now and at the moment I'm creating some wood graphics for a game. For creating the wood, I first fill the image in brown, then apply some filters and finally I have my wood texture.

The problem is that I need to get many different-sized textures. It would be really annoying always to always do each step manually. I'd prefer just to press one button and then GIMP knows to execute all the commands in sequence.

Do I have to learn GIMP scripting (and if yes, where can I start) or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe their scripting language is "[Script-Fu](http://www.gimp.org/docs/scheme_plugin)" for some documentation for it.

Here is a [Script Fu Tutorial](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-script-fu-tutorial.html)

Comment: docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-script-fu-tutorial.html has a tutorial for creating your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to some option like action in Photoshop, GIMP has a plugin can record and play sequence commands. 
You can find more information here: http://registry.gimp.org/node/25305